# Check if a string does not contains a specific substring

Tags: php, string-comparison

In SQL we have `NOT LIKE %string%`

I need to do this in PHP.

```
if ($string NOT LIKE %word%) { do something }
```

I think that can be done with `strpos()`

But can’t figure out how…

I need exactly that comparission sentence in valid PHP.

```
if ($string NOT LIKE %word%) { do something }
```

Comment: I updated the title to better reflect the question. The exact semantics of word matching should also be laid out. It may be better to use `\bword\b` or `\bword|word\b` in certain situations.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
if (strpos($string, $word) === FALSE) {
   ... not found ...
}
```

Note that [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is case sensitive, if you want a case-insensitive search, use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) instead.

Also note the `===`, forcing a strict equality test. strpos CAN return a valid `0` if the 'needle' string is at the start of the 'haystack'. By forcing a check for an actual boolean false (aka 0), you eliminate that false positive.

Comment: note that %word% is a wildcard, not a variable... the $string contains an IP address in char form, like $string = 123.456.789.100, and i want to exclude (NOT LIKE) those that start with 123.456%

Comment: @LucasMatos Then `$word = "word"` then ... while it is a wildcard, it's a very trivial usage ("floating ends") that `strpos` covers (and in fact it is *because* of this that `strpos` works here!). `$word = "a?b"` would not work with this approach, if `?` was meant to "match any character", for instance

Comment: @LUcas: should have said so in the question, then. Simple examples get simple answers.

Comment: thats how my sentence looks like `if ($viewer_ip AND $viewer_ip != $last_viewer_ip AND strpos($viewer_ip, 66.249) === false) {` i want to exclude google´s bot ips from my counter. just have to wait one of them reach my site to check if its working porperly. thanks u all

Comment: be very careful with a 'bare' floating point number like that. PHP may stringify it with different trailing decimals than you'd expect. Force it to be a string with `66.249` instead, and not that it WILL find things like `166.249`. If that's the at the START of the string, you can change the `===` to a simple `>` instead, to exclude any matches at the start.

Comment: and just a note, the substring being looked for in these __strpos and stripos__ should be an actual __word__ like 'this __name__ is reachable and not the _Name_ in __thisName__'.

Answer (score 22):

Use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). If the string is not found it returns `false`, otherwise something that is not `false`. Be sure to use a type-safe comparison (`===`) as `0` may be returned and it is a falsy value:

```
if (strpos($string, $substring) === false) {
    // substring is not found in string
}

if (strpos($string, $substring2) !== false) {
    // substring2 is found in string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
use 

if(stripos($str,'job')){
   // do your work
}
```

Comment: This will fail when `job` is the leading three characters of `$str`.  Correcting this unexplained snippet will make it a duplicate answer on this page.  This post is safe to remove.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//  Use this function and Pass Mixed string and what you want to search in mixed string.
//  For Example :
    $mixedStr = "hello world. This is john duvey";
    $searchStr= "john";

    if(strpos($mixedStr,$searchStr)) {
      echo "Your string here";
    }else {
      echo "String not here";
    }
```

Comment: This will fail if $searchStr is at the beggining of $mixedStr. In that example, if you search for "hello", you will echo "String not here", cause strpos will return 0, which will branch into the else condition.

Always use === when checking the return value of strpos.

Answer (score -1):

Kind of depends on your data, doesn't it?  strpos('a foolish idea','fool') will show a match, but may not be what you want. If dealing with words, perhaps

preg_match("!\b$word\b!i",$sentence)

is wiser.  Just a thought.

Comment: What if `$word` contains special characters?  This answer shows how to match a whole word.  The question asked how to determine if a substring is not present in an input string.